# rails store array in to database field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to store an array into a database field.
I tried the following method:

```
class MyStuff < ActiveRecord::Base  
  serialize :things
end

stuff = MyStuff.new 
stuff.things << "pen" 
stuff.things << "paper"
stuff.save
```

I get an error: "The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<"

Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is "things". Define it to be Array or Hash or something you want that to be and then add elements to it.

```
stuff = MyStuff.new 

stuff.things = []
stuff.things << "pen"
..

stuff.save
```

Comment: Do I need to use serialize?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this, this will work for existing things as well.

```
stuff.things ||= [] //without || your existing things will be reset
stuff.things << "pen"
..
```

Comment: Good point. With `.new` it doesn't matter, but with existing records, your answer will save many from deleting their data!